# Oracle: change timestamp of modified column on every row update

Tags: oracle

I work with Oracle and I'm looking for something like "ON UPDATE" in MySQL.

How can I set a timestamp automatically in my modified column every time a row in a table was changed/ updated?

Comment: Better idea: why not use temporal-tables instead?

Answer (score 0):

With a trigger.

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_test
  before insert or update on test
  for each row
begin
  :new.timestamp_column := sysdate;
end;
/
```